# Any web performance testing tool for Smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I am using Pharo 3 and I have automated my web application build process. Now it comes to testing and I want to know if there is a Smalltalk tool to do the performance testing?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of performance tests are you interested in?

Answer (score 2):

Look at SMark, a benchmarking framework: http://smalltalkhub.com/#!/~StefanMarr/SMark.

For web applications, you can also use Apache ab: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html